# U-cospectrality: Cospectral for the universal adjacency matrix

Tags: spectral-graph-theory

Consider an undirected graphs $G=(V,E)$ and its *universal adjacency matrix* [1]: $$
U_G(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=\alpha A_G + \beta I + \gamma J + \delta D_G,
$$
where $\alpha (\neq 0),\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$ are real numbers, $A_G$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$, $I$ is the identity matrix, $J$ is the ``all ones'' matrix and $D_G$ is the diagonal matrix containing the degrees of vertices in $G$ along its diagonal.

Call two undirected graphs $G=(V,E)$ and $H=(W,F)$ *$U$-cospectral* if their universal adjacency matrices $U_G(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ and $U_H(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ are co-spectral, for *all* $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$.

For specific choices of the parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$ we obtain standard notions of co-spectrality in terms of

- the adjacency matrix $A_G$, for $\alpha=1, \beta=\gamma=\delta=0$;
- the Laplacian matrix $L_G$ for $\alpha=−1, \beta=\gamma=0, \delta=1$;
- the signless Laplacian $Q_G$ for $\alpha=1, \beta=\gamma=0, \delta=1$;
- the complement adjacency matrix $\bar A_G$ for $\alpha=\beta=-1,\gamma=1,\delta=0$;
- the Seidel matrix $S_G$ for $\alpha=-2,\beta=-1,\gamma=1,\delta=0$.

Now, it is well known that $G$ and $H$ are cospectral with regards to their adjacency matrices $A_G$ and $A_H$ if and only if there is an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that $A_GO=OA_H$.

Similarly [2], $G$ and $H$ are cospectral and with regards to their adjacency matrices $A_G$ and $A_H$ and their complements $\bar A_G$ and $\bar A_H$, respectively, if and only if there is an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that $A_GO=OA_H$ and moreover, $O\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is the all ones vector.

My question relates to a generalization of such characterisations.

**QUESTION:**

1. What is the relationship between the adjacency matrices $A_G$ and $A_H$ for $U$-cospectral graphs? In other words, what kind of extra conditions should the matrix $O$ have such that $A_GO=OA_H$ iff $G$ and $H$ are $U$-cospectral?
2. More generally, is anything known when $G$ and $H$ are co-spectral with regards to any *polynomial* in terms of the adjacency, identity, all ones and diagonal with degree matrix? That is, when matrices $p(A_G,I,J,D_G)$ and $p(A_H,I,J,D_H)$ are co-spectral for any polynomial $p(x,y,z,u)$?

Is anything known about this? This question naturally arises when investigating the power of spectral approaches to differentiate between different graphs.

[1] Universal adjacency matrices with two eigenvalues. W.H. Haemers and G.R. Omidi, Linear Algebra and its Applications 435(10):2520–2529, 2011.

[2] Cospectral graphs and the generalized adjacency matrix. E.R. van Dam, W.H. Haemers, and J.H. Koolen. Linear Algebra and its Applications, 423(1):33–41, 2007.

Comment: Aren't U-cospectral graphs polynomial-U-cospectral?

Comment: I don't think so. Although being $U$-cospectral implies cospectrality of powers of the universal adjacency matrix, it may not imply that, e.g.,  $D_G+A_G^2$ and $D_H+A_H^2$ are cospectral, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry. I overlooked that.